# Yellow card or direct red card for an offense that happened 10 minutes ago?

Tags: rules, football

Can a football referee show a yellow card or a direct red card for an offense happened ten minutes ago, simply because they realise that they gave an incorrect decision for not showing the card for the offense?

Comment: I note that you have already asked a highly similar question for just the red card. The addition of the error is new, but does not change the answer for the red card. I suggest focusing on only the yellow card here, as they do have different answers.

Comment: @Nij it does. If play has resumed you can not change a previous call, unless VAR interferes.

Comment: @Gakov99 I'm not entirely sure what you want to know. Has the offence 10 min prior resulted in a free kick or did the referee nothing at all? Or did they not see it? Please be more precise.

Comment: I think you need to read my answer on that question, then. It being an error does not change the answer - if play has resumed, except in one specific circumstance, the red card cannot be shown for that offence later.

Comment: Assume that the offence did not result in a free kick.

Comment: The other answer does not cover this. Advantage rules do no apply to correcting wrong decisions. The restart of the play wasn't delayed either, because it was never stopped in the first place according to the comments.

Comment: ... so, you're saying exactly what the answer does, play has not stopped and (except for very specific circumstances) the card should be given.

Comment: @Nij the play was at least not whistled off, nor did the referee indicate advantage (mandatory in your example!). This doesn't mean the play wasn't stopped by any other means in the meantime either. Giving a card after all that is a clear rule violation by the referee. The question explicitly says incorrect decision. This isn't the case in any of your examples.

Comment: I'm still not seeing your issue. If play never stopped, the referee can do whatever they like in sanctioning offences, even if they waved it away or signalled and played advantage. If play has stopped and restarted for any reason, then except for specific situations, they cannot go back to it. That's what my answer, and LOTG, say.

Answer (score 1):

From the 2020/21 Laws of the Game:

> a disciplinary sanction may *only* be issued after play has restarted if another match official had identified and attempted to communicate the offence to the referee before play restarted; the restart associated with the sanction does not apply.

The amount of time elapsing since the offense does not change whether a disciplinary sanction (yellow or red card) can be given for it.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is VAR (video assistant referee) in certain leagues. The incident would then get reviewed and the referee could show a yellow card or a red card to the player. In certain cases, he could also remove a yellow card from a player.

Comment: Yes with VAR you can get carded for an incident from a few minutes ago. But it's hard to imagine for one from 10 minutes ago

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. As discussed in the answer to [Gakov99's other question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/25581/), there is a lot of nuance to whether any card can be given after this much time, especially for the red card. Can you refer to the laws of the game that support your answer, and handle the nuance involved?